# Can I ask multiple questions in one go?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Say I've read a philosophical book and I formulate some questions about this book about the reasoning the philosopher uses. Specific questions like:

- The philosopher puts forth these arguments ..., what is he trying to say?
- The philosopher approaches this topic in such and such way, what's his motive?

I also have some less specific questions like:

- Is this philosopher thinking inside the constraints of the era he was living in when he says ...? If yes, is he doing this willfully or is this just a curse of any thinker (or anyone)?

The questions are all about one book and have a similar theme. Then again, they are multiple questions. For efficiency and coherence I'd just ask them in one go, but I don't know if this would go against the SE format.

So (under which circumstances) can I ask multiple questions in one go? How would I best go about asking these questions above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple questions in general should be separate; you can always link between them to bring a bit more coherence. Even in the case where one question builds on another, it can be useful to have individual questions so that their answer sets will be independent and voted on separately. Like any other general rule, though, there are definitely some edge cases here; it may be reasonable to ask more than one question at once if they are *quite* closely-related and each can be answered *briefly*. But in general it's more optimal in terms of the platform to ask individual questions individually.